# Selenium not finding locators on Amazon site

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble locating elements with selenium + python on amazon.com. 
Was trying to click search button by id, or get the number of search results displayed. 
Was able to click search only once, next tries i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'. 
Basic scenario - open amazon, type value in search field and click search button next get number of displayed results.

I tried using Xpath, going up by elements hierarchy, just to make sure i can locate anything. Nothing works, it seems the page is somehow invisible.

```
def click_search_button(self):
    self.find_element(*AmazonLocators.SEARCH_BTN).click()

def find_num_of_results(self):
    raw_num = self.find_element(*AmazonLocators.NUMBER_OF_RESULTS).text

class AmazonLocators(object):
    SEARCH_BTN = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'nav-input')
    NUMBER_OF_RESULTS = (By.ID, 's-result-count')
```

Comment: wait for an element before click

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the elements will be hidden from Dom after clicking. Try using JavaScript executor:

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElementbyxpath("//[@id="js_usercenter_left"]/dl/dd[2]/a");

   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I think you need to add return before arguments[0].